# Equivalent command of "Sync" on Github windows

Tags: git, bash, github, rebase

Hi on Github for Windows you have this option : **Sync**

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/57e89b2b267e73b22ea1fb68555383c2.png]

When i want to use my git bash i don't know the equivalent of this "sync"

I mean i have to differents branch and i want to update my branch with master.

Not a simple pull, i want to use rebase too.

It's seem the button "sync" do the rebae, so what is the equivalent command prompt ?

If i use `git pull --rebase` i have :

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> foundation_grunt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rebase your branch so it is based off the current `master`:

```
git fetch
git rebase master
```

If you want to merge the changes from `master` to your branch:

```
git fetch
git merge master
```

I do not know which would be the equivalent of "Sync", but I usually rebase my branch from `master`, checkout `master`, then merge my branch, as I find this usually results in the cleanest history. The primary project I work on uses [this model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).